# Como autenticar um usuário quando o campo "username" recebe valores que podem referenciar colunas diferentes na tabela do banco?

Tags: laravel

Tenho um formulário de login onde tenho os campos "username" e "password". A dificuldade que venho encontrando é a seguinte: Quero dar a opção do usuário se logar por CPF, email ou telefone (no campo "username"). Sendo que no método attempt() da classe Auth(), que uso pra autenticar, só consigo passar valores que referenciam colunas fixas. **Veja como está o meu código no método que faz o login:**

```
public function login(Request $request){
      $array = ["error" => ''];
    
      $username = $request->input('username'); //Será passado o email,cpf ou telefone
      $password = $request->input('password');
    
      if($user && $password){
    
        $token = Auth()->attempt(['email' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
    
        if(!$token){
          return $this->unauthorized();
        }
        
        $array['token'] = $token;
      }
  }
```

Acima, aquela variável $username pode ser cpf, email ou phone (que são colunas distintas da tabela users).

Resumindo, eu quero dar a oportunidade do usuário se logar com a opção que ele desejar entre essas 3 (cpf,email e phone).

A grosso modo, só para ilustrar minha necessidade, seria algo como isso:

```
$token = Auth()->attempt(['email/cpf/phone' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
```

Vocês poderiam me ajudar quanto a isso ? Se não fui claro, avisem nos comentários que eu edito e acrescento informações.

**OBS:** Estou usando Laravel 7.

Comment: Se você tiver um meio **totalmente determinístico** para diferenciar `email` de `cpf` e de `phone` fornecido pelo usuário, você pode definir a primeira chave do array associativo dinamicamente. Caso contrário, o mais ideal é montar a _query_ manualmente e, depois de validar a autenticação, logar o usuário utilizando o método `login` (ou `setUser`), veja a [API](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/StatefulGuard.html). Não conheço muito Laravel (nunca usei, mas acho que é esse método mesmo). Enfim, essa é a ideia, espero que tenha dado para entender. :) [...]

Comment: olhando a documentação aqui não vejo outra forma de faze-lo a não ser retentando a chamada do attempt, ex if(Auth()->attempt(['email' => $username, 'password' => $password] || Auth()->attempt(['cpf' => $username, 'password' => $password]);

Comment: @LucasMiranda, puts, olhei a doc pra caramba também. Queria evitar ao máximo faz isso. Só faria assim se não houvesse outra alternativa.

Comment: @LuizFelipe , então, fiz a pergunta mais no intuito de saber se existe algo no laravel que eu usasse especificamente para isso, sem fazer possíveis "malabarismos". Se eu não encontrar, procurarei alternativas como as citadas por você e pelo Lucas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisei personalizar uma consulta de login em um projeto do trabalho e descobri como fazer. O processo não está documentado e precisa ler bastante código para entender detalhadamente como funciona. A solução é simples: sobrescreva o método [`EloquentUserProvider::retrieveByCredentials`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php#L106), o método original tem uma `$query` em que você pode fazer sua regra de negócio com condições `orWhere`.

Para isso precisa seguir algumas etapas:

1. Crie uma classe que estenda `\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider` (nesse exemplo `MeuEloquentUserProvider`;
2. Sobrescreva o método `retrieveByCredentials` de acordo com sua necessidade;
3. Informe ao framework para usar a classe personalizada `MeuEloquentUserProvider` no método `register` de algum *service provider*, recomendo o `\App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`:

```php
use \Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->extend(AuthManager::class, function(AuthManager $manager) {
        return $manager->provider('eloquent', function($app, $config) {
            return new MeuEloquentUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model']);
        });
    });
}
```

Os métodos relacionados são:

- [`\Illuminate\Container\Container::extend`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Container/Container.html#method_extend)
- [`\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::provider`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.html#method_provider)

Comment: Opa, Pedrão. Essa sua resposta foi se baseando em qual versão do Laravel ? Funciona na minha versão que mencionei na pergunta ? Pior que na sexta eu fiz maior engenharia, rs, pra fazer essa situação funcionar. Vou analisar a sua amanhã, pra ver se vale a pena substituir pela engenharia toda que eu fui obrigado a fazer por não ter visto nada que suprisse a minha necessidade.

Comment: Funciona sim. Usei essa estrutura no 5.5, deve funcionar no 7 e 8 pois o código envolvido não mudou quase nada.

Comment: Pedro, apesar da sua resposta ser útil, eu consultei alguns programadores em Laravel (galera do grupo do Laravel Brasil do Telegram) e eles disseram que ela engessa um pouco o código. Eu vou aceitar sua resposta, pq ela é sim funcional, mas vou deixar como resposta a alternativa que encontrei para resolver o problema e que achei ficar mais legível no caso de futuros erros acontecerem. Obrigado!

Comment: tem toda razão, justamente porque essa solução modifica o comportamento de classes do framework, além de ficar "escondida" de quem for fazer manutenção do código no futuro

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma personalização (um método em separado) que verifica se o dado, que o usuário que usou para tentar logar, bate com uma das colunas do banco de dados (email, cpf ou phone). **Veja esse método que foi criado:**

```
public function verifyLogin($user){
        
   $u = User::where('email', $user)->orWhere('cpf', $user)->orWhere('phone',$user)->first()->toArray();
     
   if($u)
   {
     return  $u;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Se um dos dados baterem, é retornado os dados do usuário e no método attempt() do Auth, nós usamos o id desse usuário que foi encontrado para realizar o login. **Veja como ficou o código no método login(), que é o método que faz a autenticação.**

```
public function login(Request $request){

       $array = ["error" => ''];

       $username = $request->user; //Será passado o email,cpf ou telefone
       $password = $request->password;

    if($username && $password){

       //Chamando método para verificar o tipo de login
       $data = $this->verifyLogin($username);

          
       if(!$data)
       {
           $array["error"] = "Dados Inválidos";
           return $array;
       }

       $token = Auth()->attempt(['id' => $data['id'], 'password' => $password, 'is_active' => 1]);

       if(!$token){
          return $this->unauthorized();
       }

          
       $array['token'] = $token;
       
       $user = User::select('id', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'internal_client_id', 'is_client','is_client_employee',
       'permission_id','is_active','is_spreadsheet')->where('id', '=', $data['id'])->get();
           
        $array['userData'] = $user;

        return $array;

   }else{
      $array = ["error" => 'Dados não enviados'];
   }

   return $array;
}
```

**OBS:** No meu caso, essa lógica foi aplicada levando em consideração que os campos são "unique" e que eles não são obrigatórios.

**OBS-2:** Esses dois métodos estão dentro da classe AuthController.

**OBS-3:** O *Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth*, o *Illuminate\Http\Request* e o *App\Models\User* são importados no arquivo para os métodos dessas classes serem usadas na classe AuthController.